# Сортировка списка List

Tags: c#, сортировка, list, гистограммы

Имеется список List, содержащий около 50000 значений.

Нужно отсортировать этот список таким образом, чтобы наиболее часто встречающиеся элементы были, так сказать, на поверхности. В результате должно получиться что-то вроде гистограммы.

Как найти алгоритм сортировки?

Comment: Вы хотите узнать, как лучше реализовать данную сортировку, или алгоритм у вас уже есть, и вы хотите, чтобы List при вызове Sort умел ее применять?

Answer (score 5):

Попробуйте так:

```
var lst = new List<int> { 6, 5, 7, 5, 8, 6, 7, 5, 6, 5 };
var lst2 = lst.GroupBy(x => x).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());

lst = lst.OrderByDescending(x => lst2[x]).ThenBy(x => x).ToList();
```